# Need help to create a heatmap or time series chart in grafana using bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to create a heatmap or a time series to display the number of deployments went through out the day on an hourly basis and per environment too in grafana and the data source is bigquery.

Ideally my database has two columns environment, deployed time. With these columns I would like to develop a deployment frequency chart that takes both the columns and display the frequency chart on an hourly basis if for same day and if monthly is selected then would like to see on a day basis.

I have used a simple query with count and group by functions but that is not giving me what I am looking for.

Can someone guide me on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description it seems to me, that you are looking not for heatmap (since your "second dimension" not a dimension, but set of labels), but rather for [state timeline](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/state-timeline/) or [status history](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/status-history/).

Regarding querying: calculate number of deployments on every environment at every time slot (1 hour for your case).